# Where can I find the lua script of a Co-Simulation model in OMSimulator (OpenModelica)?

Tags: openmodelica

I am trying to run a co-simulation model using OMSimulator. I managed to create a FMU from a TRNSYS model thanks to this tool: https://sourceforge.net/projects/trnsys-fmu/

When I import it, I get the following error:

[2] 12:23:32 Scripting Error
[fmiLogger] module FMI2XML: Start attribute is required for this causality, variability and initial combination

It seems that I need to initialize some variables (not sure about what) in the OMSimulator command line. I think that it is the Lua script I heard about, but I cannot really find it.

I would really appreciate it someone could help me on this, since the documentation (https://openmodelica.org/doc/OMSimulator/v2.0.1/html/OMSimulator.html) it is not enough for my level.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with the FMU and not OMSimulator. The start value is required in the modelDescription.xml file of the FMU according to the FMI specification.